# The keyword 'private' is reserved when I parse typescript code into ast

Tags: javascript, typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, jscodeshift

I want to parse this code to ast:

```
const code = `
 class Test {
  constructor(private foo: Foo) { }
 }
`;
```

But when I run I get error:

```
  The keyword 'private' is reserved
```

This is the full code:

```
import * as escodegen from "escodegen";
import { Parser } from "acorn";

const code = `
class Test {
  
  constructor(private foo: Foo) { }
}
`;

const acorn = Parser.extend(require("acorn-jsx")(), require("acorn-bigint"));

const ast = acorn.parse(code, { ranges: false, ecmaVersion: "latest" });

const output = escodegen.generate(ast);

console.log({ output });
```

In [astexplorer.net](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/259a2f700b00e540ca7be449a03be3f2/0481fd621259f712dd0853de0db71a2d30bb464c) it is works. How make it work in [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-cache-nc79h?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: both links don't use the same code, your code have the same error in `astexplorer.net` I think you are using typescript syntax in a JSX parser.

Comment: Do I need to using typescript parser? any docs for thats?

Comment: wrong ast link. updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the typescript compiler if you want to work with typescript code.
You can read more here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API

Comment: This is what astexplorer.net use?

Comment: yes, this is what they use to parse typescript